# How to connect to MS Access DB using Java + ODBC on Windows 7

Tags: java, database, ms-access, odbc, windows-7-x64

I googleed this question a lot and the answers are inconsistent and none helped. So I thought I could get a little more help here.
I need to code a little app in Java for my next class which gets data from a MS Access database(mdb) using ODBC. My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate 64bits. I know there is a odbcad32 in SysWOW64 folder.
I managed to set up a DSN there. But I can't connect. The app throws a SQL Exception. Tried two alternatives for *DriverManager.getConnection()*:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBH=E:/DB.mdb
```

and

```
jdbc:odbc:DSN_NAME
```

The driver is:

```
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

**[EDIT]**

The connection code is basically the following:

```
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        db = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL error!");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class not found!");
    }
```

**[/EDIT]**

And doesn't work. I don't know how to fix the problem because I don't know where the problem lies! If is the ODBC driver or Java or whatever.

It's too bothersome to use a virtual WinXP to do the job. This can't go on forever.

**[EDIT2]**

Just to be sure: it does work on WinXP, as implicited. :}

**[/EDIT2]**

I would appreciate a lot any help I could get here. :DDDDD

Comment: Not sure what kind of help you expect. The random bits of pseudo code you posted look reasonable, but you haven't posted your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) showing the actual demo code. You haven't stated what the SQLException is. So we have little to go on.

Comment: Edited. I hope it is enough to go on now. :D

Comment: Seems to me that if you've Googled and found unsatisfactory answers, it would make sense to include some of those answers and explain why they didn't solve your problem.

Comment: I would be happy to provide any details you needed, Mr. Fenton. 8D Seemed to me that my problem was a common one, even without a good "googleable" solution, so I thought any experienced Java programmer would easily identify the source of the problem. That's why I didn't pollute the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you since you already have setup ODBC, you might want to also make sure you are using the same 64 bit odbc driver (if you created your odbc connection under %WINDIR%\System32\odbcad32.exe). I know for a fact that there is no 64 bit driver for access 2007 so in my case, I had to create a 32 bit odbc connection(%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe), downgrade my java version to 32 bits and use the 32 bit driver to make it to work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I had in mind, but I was having trouble findind the correct version. I tried it one more time, and seems I got lucky. It is working :D Thank you very much.